# spark - stackoverflow error - org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

Ran a spark (v2.1.1) job that joins 2 rdds (one is .txt file from S3, another is parquet from S3) the job then merges the dataset (ie get latest row per PK, if PK exists in txt and parquet then take the row from the .txt) and writes out a new parquet to S3. Got this error but upon re-running it worked fine. Both the .txt and parquet have 302 columns. The .txt has 191 rows, the parquet has 156300 rows. Does anyone know the cause?

```
   18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 9.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 9 (count at BaseJob.scala:93) finished in 0.055 s
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO DAGScheduler: looking for newly runnable stages
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO DAGScheduler: running: Set()
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO DAGScheduler: waiting: Set(ResultStage 10)
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO DAGScheduler: failed: Set()
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 10 (MapPartitionsRDD[38] at count at BaseJob.scala:93), which has no missing parents
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_13 stored as values in memory (estimated size 7.0 KB, free 911.2 MB)
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_13_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.7 KB, free 911.2 MB)
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_13_piece0 in memory on 10.160.123.242:38105 (size: 3.7 KB, free: 912.1 MB)
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 13 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 10 (MapPartitionsRDD[38] at count at BaseJob.scala:93)
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 10.0 with 1 tasks
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 127, 10.160.122.226, executor 0, partition 0, NODE_LOCAL, 5948 bytes)
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_13_piece0 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 3.7 KB, free: 4.6 GB)
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 5 to 10.160.122.226:45952
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO MapOutputTrackerMaster: Size of output statuses for shuffle 5 is 163 bytes
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 127) in 18 ms on 10.160.122.226 (executor 0) (1/1)
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 10.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 10 (count at BaseJob.scala:93) finished in 0.018 s
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 4 finished: count at BaseJob.scala:93, took 0.146750 s
18/07/02 13:44:23 INFO Delta3: Count of the clean and error records are 191,0
18/07/02 13:44:24 INFO InMemoryTableScanExec: Predicate (silfstatus#190246 = 1) generates partition filter: ((silfstatus.lowerBound#199645 <= 1) && (1 <= silfstatus.upperBound#199644))
18/07/02 13:44:24 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_11_piece0 on 10.160.123.242:38105 in memory (size: 161.7 KB, free: 912.3 MB)
18/07/02 13:44:24 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_11_piece0 on 10.160.122.226:38011 in memory (size: 161.7 KB, free: 4.6 GB)
18/07/02 13:44:24 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_13_piece0 on 10.160.123.242:38105 in memory (size: 3.7 KB, free: 912.3 MB)
18/07/02 13:44:24 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_13_piece0 on 10.160.122.226:38011 in memory (size: 3.7 KB, free: 4.6 GB)
18/07/02 13:44:24 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_12_piece0 on 10.160.123.242:38105 in memory (size: 4.4 KB, free: 912.3 MB)
18/07/02 13:44:24 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_12_piece0 on 10.160.122.226:38011 in memory (size: 4.4 KB, free: 4.6 GB)
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: take at Utils.scala:28
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 5 (take at Utils.scala:28) with 1 output partitions
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 11 (take at Utils.scala:28)
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 11 (MapPartitionsRDD[42] at take at Utils.scala:28), which has no missing parents
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_14 stored as values in memory (estimated size 611.5 KB, free 911.4 MB)
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_14_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 164.7 KB, free 911.2 MB)
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_14_piece0 in memory on 10.160.123.242:38105 (size: 164.7 KB, free: 912.1 MB)
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 14 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 11 (MapPartitionsRDD[42] at take at Utils.scala:28)
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 11.0 with 1 tasks
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 128, 10.160.122.226, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6578 bytes)
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_14_piece0 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 164.7 KB, free: 4.6 GB)
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 128) in 127 ms on 10.160.122.226 (executor 0) (1/1)
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 11.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 11 (take at Utils.scala:28) finished in 0.127 s
18/07/02 13:44:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 5 finished: take at Utils.scala:28, took 0.152945 s
18/07/02 13:44:27 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_14_piece0 on 10.160.123.242:38105 in memory (size: 164.7 KB, free: 912.3 MB)
18/07/02 13:44:27 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_14_piece0 on 10.160.122.226:38011 in memory (size: 164.7 KB, free: 4.6 GB)
18/07/02 13:44:27 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3394
18/07/02 13:44:27 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3395
18/07/02 13:44:28 INFO InMemoryTableScanExec: Predicate (silfstatus#190246 = 0) generates partition filter: ((silfstatus.lowerBound#201463 <= 0) && (0 <= silfstatus.upperBound#201462))
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO Upsert$: =====Joining the source file and previous hive partition=====
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Pruning directories with:
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Post-Scan Filters:
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Output Data Schema: struct<>
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Pushed Filters:
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 11.072558 ms
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_15 stored as values in memory (estimated size 301.6 KB, free 911.7 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_15_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 25.6 KB, free 911.7 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_15_piece0 in memory on 10.160.123.242:38105 (size: 25.6 KB, free: 912.2 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 15 from count at Data.scala:23
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO FileSourceScanExec: Planning scan with bin packing, max size: 48443541 bytes, open cost is considered as scanning 4194304 bytes.
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at Data.scala:23
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 52 (count at Data.scala:23)
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 6 (count at Data.scala:23) with 1 output partitions
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 13 (count at Data.scala:23)
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 12)
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List(ShuffleMapStage 12)
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ShuffleMapStage 12 (MapPartitionsRDD[52] at count at Data.scala:23), which has no missing parents
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_16 stored as values in memory (estimated size 9.4 KB, free 911.6 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:53 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_16_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.9 KB, free 911.6 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_16_piece0 in memory on 10.160.123.242:38105 (size: 4.9 KB, free: 912.2 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:54 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 16 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
18/07/02 13:51:54 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 4 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 12 (MapPartitionsRDD[52] at count at Data.scala:23)
18/07/02 13:51:54 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 12.0 with 4 tasks
18/07/02 13:51:54 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 129, 10.160.122.226, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 9110 bytes)
18/07/02 13:51:54 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 130, 10.160.122.226, executor 0, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 9110 bytes)
18/07/02 13:51:54 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 131, 10.160.122.226, executor 0, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 9110 bytes)
18/07/02 13:51:54 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 132, 10.160.122.226, executor 0, partition 3, PROCESS_LOCAL, 9110 bytes)
18/07/02 13:51:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_16_piece0 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 4.9 KB, free: 4.6 GB)
18/07/02 13:51:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_15_piece0 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 25.6 KB, free: 4.6 GB)
18/07/02 13:51:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 129) in 1169 ms on 10.160.122.226 (executor 0) (1/4)
18/07/02 13:51:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 132) in 1174 ms on 10.160.122.226 (executor 0) (2/4)
18/07/02 13:51:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 130) in 1394 ms on 10.160.122.226 (executor 0) (3/4)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 131) in 2292 ms on 10.160.122.226 (executor 0) (4/4)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 12.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 12 (count at Data.scala:23) finished in 2.293 s
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: looking for newly runnable stages
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: running: Set()
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: waiting: Set(ResultStage 13)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: failed: Set()
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 13 (MapPartitionsRDD[55] at count at Data.scala:23), which has no missing parents
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_17 stored as values in memory (estimated size 7.0 KB, free 911.6 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_17_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.7 KB, free 911.6 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_17_piece0 in memory on 10.160.123.242:38105 (size: 3.7 KB, free: 912.2 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 17 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 13 (MapPartitionsRDD[55] at count at Data.scala:23)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 13.0 with 1 tasks
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 133, 10.160.122.226, executor 0, partition 0, NODE_LOCAL, 5949 bytes)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_17_piece0 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 3.7 KB, free: 4.6 GB)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 6 to 10.160.122.226:45952
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO MapOutputTrackerMaster: Size of output statuses for shuffle 6 is 153 bytes
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 133) in 12 ms on 10.160.122.226 (executor 0) (1/1)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 13.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 13 (count at Data.scala:23) finished in 0.012 s
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 6 finished: count at Data.scala:23, took 2.315589 s
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: load at Data.scala:25
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 7 (load at Data.scala:25) with 1 output partitions
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 14 (load at Data.scala:25)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 14 (MapPartitionsRDD[57] at load at Data.scala:25), which has no missing parents
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_18 stored as values in memory (estimated size 74.6 KB, free 911.6 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_18_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 27.2 KB, free 911.5 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_18_piece0 in memory on 10.160.123.242:38105 (size: 27.2 KB, free: 912.2 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 18 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 14 (MapPartitionsRDD[57] at load at Data.scala:25)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 14.0 with 1 tasks
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 134, 10.160.122.226, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6337 bytes)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_18_piece0 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 27.2 KB, free: 4.6 GB)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 134) in 295 ms on 10.160.122.226 (executor 0) (1/1)
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 14.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 14 (load at Data.scala:25) finished in 0.295 s
18/07/02 13:51:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 7 finished: load at Data.scala:25, took 0.310932 s
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Pruning directories with:
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Post-Scan Filters:
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Output Data Schema: struct<row_id: string, created: timestamp, created_by: string, last_upd: timestamp, last_upd_by: string ... 300 more fields>
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Pushed Filters:
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_19 stored as values in memory (estimated size 387.2 KB, free 911.2 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_19_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 33.7 KB, free 911.1 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_19_piece0 in memory on 10.160.123.242:38105 (size: 33.7 KB, free: 912.2 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 19 from cache at Upsert.scala:25
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO FileSourceScanExec: Planning scan with bin packing, max size: 48443541 bytes, open cost is considered as scanning 4194304 bytes.
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: take at Utils.scala:28
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 8 (take at Utils.scala:28) with 1 output partitions
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 15 (take at Utils.scala:28)
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 15 (MapPartitionsRDD[65] at take at Utils.scala:28), which has no missing parents
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_20 stored as values in memory (estimated size 321.5 KB, free 910.8 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_20_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 93.0 KB, free 910.7 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_20_piece0 in memory on 10.160.123.242:38105 (size: 93.0 KB, free: 912.1 MB)
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 20 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 15 (MapPartitionsRDD[65] at take at Utils.scala:28)
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 15.0 with 1 tasks
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 135, 10.160.122.226, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 9035 bytes)
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_20_piece0 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 93.0 KB, free: 4.6 GB)
18/07/02 13:51:57 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_19_piece0 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 33.7 KB, free: 4.6 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:05 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_61_0 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 38.9 MB, free: 4.5 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_63_0 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 38.9 MB, free: 4.5 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 135) in 11751 ms on 10.160.122.226 (executor 0) (1/1)
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 15.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 15 (take at Utils.scala:28) finished in 11.751 s
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 8 finished: take at Utils.scala:28, took 11.772561 s
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 185.277258 ms
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3459
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3452
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3456
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3455
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3458
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3450
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3460
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3449
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_18_piece0 on 10.160.123.242:38105 in memory (size: 27.2 KB, free: 912.1 MB)
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_18_piece0 on 10.160.122.226:38011 in memory (size: 27.2 KB, free: 4.5 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3462
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_17_piece0 on 10.160.123.242:38105 in memory (size: 3.7 KB, free: 912.1 MB)
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_17_piece0 on 10.160.122.226:38011 in memory (size: 3.7 KB, free: 4.5 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3451
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3684
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_15_piece0 on 10.160.123.242:38105 in memory (size: 25.6 KB, free: 912.1 MB)
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_15_piece0 on 10.160.122.226:38011 in memory (size: 25.6 KB, free: 4.5 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3453
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3457
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_16_piece0 on 10.160.123.242:38105 in memory (size: 4.9 KB, free: 912.2 MB)
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_16_piece0 on 10.160.122.226:38011 in memory (size: 4.9 KB, free: 4.5 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned shuffle 6
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3461
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_20_piece0 on 10.160.123.242:38105 in memory (size: 93.0 KB, free: 912.2 MB)
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_20_piece0 on 10.160.122.226:38011 in memory (size: 93.0 KB, free: 4.5 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3454
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 9 (run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) with 4 output partitions
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 16 (run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 16 (MapPartitionsRDD[67] at run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149), which has no missing parents
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_21 stored as values in memory (estimated size 321.7 KB, free 911.3 MB)
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_21_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 93.0 KB, free 911.2 MB)
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_21_piece0 in memory on 10.160.123.242:38105 (size: 93.0 KB, free: 912.2 MB)
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 21 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 4 missing tasks from ResultStage 16 (MapPartitionsRDD[67] at run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 16.0 with 4 tasks
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 136, 10.160.122.226, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 9098 bytes)
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 137, 10.160.122.226, executor 0, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 9098 bytes)
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 138, 10.160.122.226, executor 0, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 9098 bytes)
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 139, 10.160.122.226, executor 0, partition 3, PROCESS_LOCAL, 9098 bytes)
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_21_piece0 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 93.0 KB, free: 4.5 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 136) in 47 ms on 10.160.122.226 (executor 0) (1/4)
18/07/02 13:52:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_61_2 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 38.8 MB, free: 4.5 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_61_3 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 38.7 MB, free: 4.4 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_61_1 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 38.8 MB, free: 4.4 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:49 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_63_2 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 38.8 MB, free: 4.3 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 138) in 10368 ms on 10.160.122.226 (executor 0) (2/4)
18/07/02 13:52:50 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_63_3 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 38.7 MB, free: 4.3 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:50 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 139) in 10617 ms on 10.160.122.226 (executor 0) (3/4)
18/07/02 13:52:50 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_63_1 in memory on 10.160.122.226:38011 (size: 38.8 MB, free: 4.3 GB)
18/07/02 13:52:50 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 137) in 10668 ms on 10.160.122.226 (executor 0) (4/4)
18/07/02 13:52:50 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 16.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
18/07/02 13:52:50 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 16 (run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) finished in 10.669 s
18/07/02 13:52:50 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 9 finished: run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149, took 10.684407 s
18/07/02 13:52:50 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 7.746892 ms
18/07/02 13:52:50 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_22 stored as values in memory (estimated size 19.0 MB, free 892.2 MB)
18/07/02 13:52:50 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_22_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.2 MB, free 889.0 MB)
18/07/02 13:52:50 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_22_piece0 in memory on 10.160.123.242:38105 (size: 3.2 MB, free: 909.0 MB)
18/07/02 13:52:50 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 22 from run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149
18/07/02 13:52:50 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_21_piece0 on 10.160.123.242:38105 in memory (size: 93.0 KB, free: 909.0 MB)
18/07/02 13:52:50 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_21_piece0 on 10.160.122.226:38011 in memory (size: 93.0 KB, free: 4.3 GB)  
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$sameResult$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:373)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$sameResult$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:373)
                at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$forall$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:101)
                at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$forall$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:101)
                at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$exists$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:92)
                at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$exists$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:90)
                at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
                at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$.exists$extension(Tuple2Zipped.scala:90)
                at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$.forall$extension(Tuple2Zipped.scala:101)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.sameResult(QueryPlan.scala:373)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$sameResult$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:373)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$sameResult$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:373)
                at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$forall$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:101)
                at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$forall$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:101)
                at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$exists$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:92)
                at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$exists$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:90)
                at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
                at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$.exists$extension(Tuple2Zipped.scala:90)
                at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$.forall$extension(Tuple2Zipped.scala:101)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.sameResult(QueryPlan.scala:373)
```

code ran:

```
object Upsert {
 val logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)
def finalDf(srcDf: DataFrame, partitionPath: Option[String], hiveSchema: StructType, pkList: List[String], srcSchema: StructType) = {
 logger.info(s"""=====Joining the source file and previous hive partition=====""")
 //val hiveCols = srcSchema.map(f => col(f.name))
 val srcCols = srcSchema.map(f => col("_" + f.name))
 val finalColsType = srcSchema.map(f =>
 if(f.dataType.simpleString.contains("decimal")) (f.name, DecimalType(31,8)) 
 else (f.name, f.dataType)
 )
 val finalCols = finalColsType.map(_._1)
 val srcPkList = pkList.map("_" + _)
 val hivedf = extract.Data.readHivePartition(sparkSession, partitionPath, hiveSchema).cache()
 val hiveCols = hivedf.dtypes.toList.map(n => (n._1, stringToStructTypeMapping(n._2)))
 val addedCols = finalColsType.toList.diff(hiveCols)
 val hivedfNew = addMultipleColToDF(hivedf, addedCols).select(finalCols.map(col(_)):_*).cache()
 val commonDataFilterCond = srcPkList
 .zip(pkList)
 .map{case(c1, c2) => (coalesce(col(c1), lit("null")) === coalesce(col(c2), lit("null")))}
 .reduce(_ && _)
isDfEmpty(hivedfNew) match {
 case true => srcDf
 case false => {
 val srcRename = srcDf.toDF(srcSchema.map("_" + _.name):_*)
 val joinData = srcRename.join(hivedfNew, commonDataFilterCond, "inner")
 val commonData = joinData.select(srcCols:_*)
 val currentData = srcRename.except(commonData).cache
 val prevData = hivedfNew.except(joinData.select(finalCols.map(col(_)):_*))
 currentData.unionAll(prevData).unionAll(commonData).toDF(finalCols:_*)
 }
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: A `StackOverflowError` is almost always the result of a recursive method, which never properly resolves. Some method is continually calling itself. Please post the code which preforms your logic, this is where the issue will be.

Comment: have posted the code

Comment: Hrm.. I do not even see this log entry in the output posted... Are you sure this is the output from this snippet? I would expect to see the log message before any processing begins.

Comment: have posted more of the log now, it shows that log entry